# shinyWidgets::verticalTabPanel() not working with Shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny

The app below contains a module that renders a vertical tab panel in the UI. I call this module twice in the app.

The first instance of the module renders correctly:

[image]

However, the second instance does not (the content of the tabs is no longer visible):

[image]

If you check out the inspector, you can see that for the first instance, the HTML dependencies are appended to the tabset:

[image: ![enter image description here]

However, these dependencies are missing for the second instance:

[image]

I'm guessing this is due to the use of `singleton()` in the source code for `verticalTabsetPanel`? I don't know how to get around this. I tried adding the dependencies in the `\www` folder in my app directory and then manually prepending them to the head of my app but that doesn't seem to work either, any insight as to why would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

modui <- function(id) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    verticalTabsetPanel(
      id = ns('tabs'), 
      verticalTabPanel(ns('item1'), ns('item1 content')), 
      verticalTabPanel(ns('item2'), ns('item2 content'))
    )
  )

}


modserver = function(input, output, session) {

}


# HEADER ------------------------------------------------------------------


header <- dashboardHeader()


# SIDEBAR -----------------------------------------------------------------


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = 'tab_1'), 
    menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = 'tab_2'))
)



# BODY --------------------------------------------------------------------


body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "vertical-tab-panel.css"),
    tags$script(src='vertical-tab-panel.js'),
    tags$script(src='vertical-tab-panel-bindings.js')
  ),

  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = 'tab_1', modui('t1')),
    tabItem(tabName = 'tab_2', modui('t2'))  )
)



# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------


ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


shinyApp(
  ui = ui,
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    callModule(modserver, 't1')

    callModule(modserver, 't2')

  }
)
```

Comment: Your example works for me. The content of the tabs is displayed in all situations. Did you try restarting your R session?

Comment: @bretauv yes, I have tried that. So the tab content is visible for the second tabset at your end? Have you tried toggling between the individual tabs?

Comment: Yes, I have the content `t2-item2 content` or `t2-item1 content` for the second tabset according to the individual, and same thing with t1 in the first tabset. It still works when toggling between tabs

Comment: @bretauv, when I navigate to tabset 2 on app startup, the content for the first tab is initially visible but disappears once I toggle to the second tab and back.

Comment: Everything works fine for me, maybe the problem comes from the js or css scripts you use

Comment: I sourced the dependencies from the shinyWidgets package itself.and am not using any other scripts. Tried the app on Chrome, Firefox and IE to no avail :(

Comment: A package update from v0.4.8 to 0.5.1 did the trick haha! Thanks for confirming that it worked on your end @bretauv, it helped me narrow down the problem.